# How do you add textbox and have "edit" function switch to a "Done" javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I am a novice when it comes to JS programming and I have racked my brain on trying to figure this out. Can anyone show me how this would be done?

I have a "Add" button and an "edit" button. When you click on the "Add" button a text field would appear below to enter in a name. At the same time the "Edit" button is then changes to the "Done" button so that when finished entering the text, it needs to appear on that page after clicking on the "Done" button. Lastly, when "Done" is clicked "Edit" button returns back.

Here's another craziness, so when your done adding text the "Edit" button is functioned so that when clicked the delete buttons appear to the right of the name.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: It's not perfectly clear here what's escaping you. Do you not know how you can manipulate HTML elements (or, 'DOM manipulation')? Are you not sure how to change the text of a button, or make an element appear/disappear? We're absolutely here to help, but we also won't do your homework for you.

Comment: Add a separate button for each task, and show/hide them as needed.

Comment: You should always show your code.

Answer (score -1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/XcgEC/)

You can make the elements hidden which you don't want to show and then just call JS function to set the visiblity of those elements as required.

Try this

```
 Add<input type="text" id="text" style="display:none" />
 <br>
 <button id="add" onclick="add()" name="add" value="Add">Add</button>
 <button id="edit" name="add" value="Edit">Edit</button>
 <button id="done" onclick="done()" name="add" value="Done" style="display:none">Done</button>
```

Javascript

```
function add() {
document.getElementById('edit').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('done').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('text').style.display = "block";
}

function done() {
document.getElementById('done').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('edit').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('text').style.display = "none";

}
```